# 504 Error for Cloudfront.net distribution and Route53 Domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, yaml, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to setup a static S3 website to be reachable via my custom domain, but when I've tested my cloudfront URL I'm getting 504 Error and in the logs, I see the following:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>ZFD3NVWGP7DE08W1</RequestId>
<HostId>o2iGHpwIdQjHQ51nG6HwoFtCx5QE9l0rZytYatSMF3zOVjKpHg00ph2vSAiUYJog5ZVsnxr5C18=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Here is my bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "MyPolicy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xyz-cloud-website/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've checked my S3 bucket settings as explained in the AWS documentation but as far as I can tell, all of the following is true:

- My objects are publicly accessible
- My objects are not KMS-encrypted
- My account owns both the bucket and the objects

I built this via an IaC SAM CLI deployment with the following template:

```
Resources:
  MyWebsite:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      AccessControl: PublicRead
      WebsiteConfiguration:
        IndexDocument: index.html
      BucketName: xyz-cloud-website

  MyRoute53Record:
    Type: "AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup"
    Properties:
      HostedZoneId: 00000000000000000 
      RecordSets:
        - Name: xyz-website.com
          Type: A
          AliasTarget:
            HostedZoneId: Z2FDTNDATAQYW2
            DNSName: !GetAtt MyDistribution.DomainName

  MyDistribution:
    Type: "AWS::CloudFront::Distribution"
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        ViewerCertificate:
          AcmCertificateArn: !Ref MyCertificate
          SslSupportMethod: sni-only
        Aliases:
          - xyz-website.com
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: allow-all
          TargetOriginId: xyz-cloud-website.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com
          DefaultTTL: 0
          MinTTL: 0
          MaxTTL: 0
          ForwardedValues:
            QueryString: "false"
        Origins:
          - DomainName: xyz-cloud-website.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com
            Id: xyz-cloud-website.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com
            CustomOriginConfig:
              OriginProtocolPolicy: match-viewer
        Enabled: "true"
        DefaultRootObject: index.html
```

When I access my static s3 bucket via xyz-cloud-website.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com, I have no issues. It's only when I try to use my xyz123.cloudfront.net URL or the custom domain that I get the 504.

My Cloudfront Domain, Alt, and Origin all look correct... any ideas on why this would be throwing a 504 error when I try to use Cloudfront? Trying to avoid throwing money at AWS for help on a personal project.

*Note I've obviously masked my URLs in these examples. The correct ones are in my template and are appearing in the AWS Console.

Comment: Did you also configure the custom error document on AWS?

Comment: @ruby_newbie Yes, I've got a custom error for 504 that points back to my index.html that I tried after first running into the issue. Still happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this one out. CloudFront wants a slightly different input for the Origin as a result of more recent updates that makes the old method of demarking static S3 bucket websites a bit different now.

So instead of:

```
        Origins:
          - DomainName: xyz-cloud-website.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com
            Id: xyz-cloud-website.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com
            CustomOriginConfig:
              OriginProtocolPolicy: match-viewer
```

It should be something more like:

```
        Origins:
          - DomainName: xyz-cloud-website.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
            Id: xyz-cloud-website.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
            CustomOriginConfig:
              OriginProtocolPolicy: match-viewer # OR HTTPS-only if appropriate, as it was in my case
```

This now has my CloudFront AND Custom Domain displaying as intended. This can also be achieved via the console.

Comment: Is there a news announcement or any specific documentation for this? My old website using the s3-website-<region> structure is still working but a new website using the same setup is failing for both my custom domain and CloudFront (but works for the origin). Just want to know if this is an officially approved solution or if it's a workaround that might randomly break in the future.